# How to fix hover not activating

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover

I have a website that shows designs using bootstraps card-decks. I used css to make sure that the cards always have the same width and height, but i want that when the user hovers over the image that it displays in its full resolution. it seems that it is not picking up how i am using my selector

I have tried looking through the CSS and bootstrap documentation but I can't quite find where my code is wrong.

HTML code:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-start ">

      <div class="card-deck d-flex justify-content-start">
     <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
       <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568312442641-d6c790fdf0f6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" alt="">
       <div class="card-img-overlay">
         <h5 class="card-title"><a class="text-white" href="C:\Users\Bruno\Desktop\bootstrap try outs\project find images\nature.html">Nature</a></h5>


       </div>

     </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

CSS code which i use to get the same resolution for all cards

```
.card-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

CSS code that should make the img full-size on hover.
(I also tried using only the class selector)

```
div>.card-img:hover{
  width: 10%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
  object-fit: cover!important;
}
```

I want that when the user hovers over the image, it regains its original resolution so that the user doesn't only see the cropped image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.card-img-overlay` div is sitting untop the image, so the hover effect never gets triggered
Even if it were to get triggered, i still don't think it will achieve what you want, because the image will flicker. What you want to do is best done with JavaScript `mouseenter` event